# How seed node works in Cassandra cluster

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cloud, cluster-computing

My understanding is :

Seed node maintains all the nodes list in cluster.
Lets say if we have to add a new node to the cluster, we have to enter the new node name in the seed list of seed server and then new node will be part of the ring.

I am assuming we don't have to mention any thing about the seed server in the peer nodes.

correct me if my understanding incorrect.

I read some where Failure in "Seed Node" doesn't cause any problem. Lets say if the seed node is crashed how the ring information is maintained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the other way round: In the configuration of your new node you point to another, already existing node as the seed provider. The seed-provider is the initial contact point for a new node joining a cluster. After the node has joined the cluster it remembers the topology and does not require the seed provider any more.

From the [Cassandra docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architectureGossipAbout_c.html):

> Note: The seed node designation has no purpose other than
>   bootstrapping the gossip process for new nodes joining the cluster.
>   Seed nodes are not a single point of failure, nor do they have any
>   other special purpose in cluster operations beyond the bootstrapping
>   of nodes.

Answer (score 14):

I want to clarify because that quote from the docs is old and is was never exactly precise.

**Even after bootstrapping, seed nodes still play a role in Gossip.**

There is no additional impact if you have a seed node that goes down. Though if you need to replace a seed node you should follow the [guide in the docs.](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_replace_seed_node.html)

#### Details:

In addition to helping new nodes bootstrap, seed nodes are also used to prevent split brain in your cluster. A node finds out about other nodes when it handshakes with a node that already has information about other nodes from recent gossip operations.

Gossip.run() happens every second. In a single gossip run a node will handshake with one random live node, one random dead node--if any--based on some probability, and one random seed node if the random node wasn't seed--also based on some probability. As your list of seed nodes increases, the more nodes you will be handshaking with. Per this [logic](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8896a70b015102c212d0a27ed1f4e1f0fabe85c4/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/Gossiper.java#L649-L653), the probabilistic frequency with which handshakes to the list of seed nodes occurs will increase as your proportion of seed nodes increases.

However, as noted above, step 3 only happens if step 1 did not occur on a seed node. So the probability of having to do step 3 increases with added seeds, maxing out at the point where half your nodes are seeds (.25 chance) and then decreases again.

It is recommended to keep 3 seed nodes per DC. **Do not add all your nodes as seed nodes**